# How to reset the sequence for IDs on PostgreSQL tables

Tags: django, postgresql

I recently imported a lot of data from an old database into a new Postgresql database as the basis for models in a new Django site.

I used the IDs from the old database (as rows in various tables refer to each other), but they aren't all sequential - there are often large gaps.

I've noticed that when I add a new object via the Django app, then it has been using IDs starting from 1, which hasn't been a problem so far as there were no rows with very low IDs.

But once it reaches the first row of legacy data, then postgres obviously complains:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_comments_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(25) already exists.
```

Looking at the table descriptions I'm guessing I need to reset some kind of sequence on each table:

```
                                      Table "public.django_comments"
     Column      |           Type           |                          Modifiers                           
-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('django_comments_id_seq'::regclass)
...
```

What do I need to do to reset that sequence, so that new rows are added with IDs higher than the current maximum ID?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Run [sqlsequencereset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset) and it'll print all the reset commands you need.

Comment: I never thought there'd be a Django-specific way to get at what I was after! Thanks Dmitry.

Comment: And with this you can do: `python manage.py sqlsequencereset app_name | python manage.py dbshell` and it will be executed automatically

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that always makes me wonder why Django isn't *way* more popular. Still available in 2.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset

Comment: @VStoykov Thanks a lot. The combined version of command `python manage.py sqlsequencereset app_name | python manage.py dbshell` saved my life + time both.

Answer (score 29):

As suggested by "Dmitry Shevchenko" you can run `sqlsequencereset` to solve your problem.

or

You can execute the SQL query generated by `sqlsequencereset` from within python in this way (*using the default database*):

```
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from django.db import connection

from myapps.models import MyModel1, MyModel2


sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), [MyModel1, MyModel2])
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for sql in sequence_sql:
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

I tested this code with **Python3.6**, **Django 2.0** and **PostgreSQL 10**.

Comment: Calling `sqlsequencereset` as suggested by others only print the sql commands. This solution actually executes those commands, so this is the real solutions. Thanks

Comment: Also, if you import `from django.apps import apps`; you can replace `[MyModel1, MyModel2]` with `apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)` to run this against all of your models (which may be useful after an initial data import).

Comment: Another upside of this approach is you can choose exact models you want to run sequence reset against whereas `sqlsequencereset` prints out a reset SQL for all models under the specified app.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a short snippet to reset all sequences in Django 1.9+ (based on http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2774/) and compatible with Python 3:

```
import os
from io import StringIO

os.environ['DJANGO_COLORS'] = 'nocolor'

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import connection

commands = StringIO()
cursor = connection.cursor()

for app in apps.get_app_configs():
    label = app.label
    call_command('sqlsequencereset', label, stdout=commands)

cursor.execute(commands.getvalue())
```

Comment: If you wondering why you get SQL syntax error, check if you got


    os.environ['DJANGO_COLORS'] = 'nocolor'


in your code. this would escape unicode color instructions in the output of sqlsequencereset

Comment: This is optimal solution if youi want to include in migrations. Thank you so much

Answer (score 9):

So the quickest, easiest and most "Django" way to do this in my opinion is to use the following management command:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset app_name
```

After this, you'll get something such as:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"measurements_quantity"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "measurements.Quantities";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"measurements.Prefixes"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "measurements.Prefixes";
COMMIT;
```

The next step is to run this in the `python manage.py dbshell` management command, so run this and then you'll see the interaction database shell in your terminal:

```
psql (11.7 (Debian 11.7-0+deb10u1), server 11.5 (Debian 11.5-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=# SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"measurements.Quantities"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "measurements.Quantities";
 setval 
--------
      1
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"measurements.Prefixes"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "measurements.Prefixes";
 setval 
--------
      1
(1 row)

postgres=# COMMIT;
COMMIT
postgres=# exit
```

Simple as that. The `python manage.py sqlsequencereset app_name` command will give you the SQL you need to run, and you run it in the `dbshell`.

No writing your own custom SQL or custom code and it will give you what you need in the correct format and db engine of choice.

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL Command:
`ALTER SEQUENCE app_model_id_seq RESTART WITH 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
select setval('django_comments_id_seq', 12345);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess `max('id')` instead of `12345` would work? But Dmitry's Django-specific solution is probably best for me this time.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet [Run sqlsequencereset on all apps](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2774/) reset all IDs of all Empty Models

Comment: This is out of date since Django 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more-or-less completely dynamic solution I just implemented in a management command that has no restriction as to the name of the Primary Key you are attempting to reset as it gathers it based on the connection params you have in **settings**.

The only sequencing I could not reset included PKs that are not integers, which is apparent in the PK for **django.contrib.sessions**, but again I have never run into sequencing errors with that so I doubt it is an issue.

Here is the command, run using `python manage.py reset_sequences` (obviously as long as your file/command is named reset_sequences.py)

```
import psycopg2
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import connections


def dictfetchall(cursor):
    """Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"""
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Resets sequencing errors in Postgres which normally occur due to importing/restoring a DB"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # loop over all databases in system to figure out the tables that need to be reset
        for name_to_use_for_connection, connection_settings in settings.DATABASES.items():
            db_name = connection_settings['NAME']
            host = connection_settings['HOST']
            user = connection_settings['USER']
            port = connection_settings['PORT']
            password = connection_settings['PASSWORD']

            # connect to this specific DB
            conn_str = f"host={host} port={port} user={user} password={password}"

            conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
            conn.autocommit = True

            select_all_table_statement = f"""SELECT *
                                    FROM information_schema.tables
                                    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
                                    ORDER BY table_name;
                                """
            # just a visual representation of where we are
            print('-' * 20, db_name)
            try:
                not_reset_tables = list()
                # use the specific name for the DB
                with connections[name_to_use_for_connection].cursor() as cursor:
                    # using the current db as the cursor connection
                    cursor.execute(select_all_table_statement)
                    rows = dictfetchall(cursor)
                    # will loop over table names in the connected DB
                    for row in rows:
                        find_pk_statement = f"""
                            SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME
                            FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
                            LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
                            USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
                            WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
                                AND t.table_name='{row['table_name']}';
                        """
                        cursor.execute(find_pk_statement)
                        pk_column_names = dictfetchall(cursor)
                        for pk_dict in pk_column_names:
                            column_name = pk_dict['column_name']

                        # time to build the reset sequence command for each table
                        # taken from django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset
                        # example: SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"[TABLE]"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "[TABLE]";
                        try:
                            reset_statement = f"""SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"{row['table_name']}"','{column_name}'), 
                                                    coalesce(max("{column_name}"), 1), max("{column_name}") IS NOT null) FROM "{row['table_name']}" """
                            cursor.execute(reset_statement)
                            return_values = dictfetchall(cursor)
                            # will be 1 row
                            for value in return_values:
                                print(f"Sequence reset to {value['setval']} for {row['table_name']}")
                        except Exception as ex:
                            # will only fail if PK is not an integer...
                            # currently in my system this is from django.contrib.sessions
                            not_reset_tables.append(f"{row['table_name']} not reset")

            except psycopg2.Error as ex:
                raise SystemExit(f'Error: {ex}')

            conn.close()
            print('-' * 5, ' ALL ERRORS ', '-' * 5)
            for item_statement in not_reset_tables:
                # shows which tables produced errors, so far I have only
                # seen this with PK's that are not integers because of the MAX() method
                print(item_statement)

            # just a visual representation of where we are
            print('-' * 20, db_name)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Paolo Melchiorre I created a custom management command, which populates all the models from chosen apps.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.apps import apps
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from django.db import connection

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stdout.write('Reset AutoFields ...')
        APPS = ['app1', 'app2']

        APPS = [apps.get_app_config(app) for app in APPS]
        models = []
        for app in APPS:
            models.extend(list(app.get_models()))

        sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), models)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for sql in sequence_sql:
                self.stdout.write(sql)
                cursor.execute(sql)
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Reset AutoField complete.'))
```

tested using `python 3.7` and `django 2.2`.

Comment: Use APPS = apps.get_app_configs() # Get all installed apps configs