# What causes postgresql to mess up the sequence?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm fairly new to Postgresql and it's really weird for me that It can't keep track of auto increment fields.

I have these tables I'm using for my django app

```
Article
Article_Category
Category
```

Everything was working fine until today. The Article table suddenly forgot what was the last Article_id and started creating id's back to 1.

Comment: Something reset the sequence. Do you have `log_statement = all` set in your PostgreSQL server? Did you run any tests that might've "helpfully" reset it?

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL handles sequences independent of the tables they're used in.

Comment: Did you recreate your tables? What did you do today?

Comment: Craig,
I checked my settings and log_statement is commented.

Ignacio,
Sorry but what do you mean by handles sequence independent of tables?

mu,
Nope. It's hosted on a Linode server and the last time I remembered doing is rebooting Linode. But I never touched the database prior to this.

Comment: You can check your sequences' current states with f.ex. `SELECT * FROM "Article_Article_id_seq";`. You should read the manual about PostgreSQL's sequences/serials: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL . Also django has a specific tool handling this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589634/how-to-reset-the-sequence-for-ids-on-postgresql-tables . Without more information, we can just wild guess what can cause this.

Comment: pozs, I'll take a look at those links. Thank You!