# PostgreSQL + Django AutoField id doesn't get restarted after flush

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-nose

I am currently testing Django project using `django-nose`. I use PostgreSQL for my DB. The problem I am facing is:

In test `setUp` method I create one Emp instance and save it. Then I execute this:

```
Emp.objects.filter(empId=1)
```

but this doesn't exist. During debugging I figured that the Emp instance exists in DB but its ID is 137.

I presume that is the issue with django-nose as it flushes DB after every test, however previous empId's seem to remain.

Note: I am using:

```
class Emp(models.Model):
    empId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

My question is, how do I resolve this issue? Is there a way to restart id auto-increment routine after every `setUp` call?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589634/how-to-reset-the-sequence-for-ids-on-postgresql-tables

Comment: my app with Emp model is named employee, therefore I have already tried 'python manage.py sqlsequencereset employee' which didn't solve my issue

Comment: Ok. However, I think it's not a good way to rely on a specific ID when running unit tests. Why not something like `Emp.objects.first()` or `Emp.objects.get()` if you're sure you have only 1 Emp object during your test?

Comment: That's completely true and that's how I resolved this problem in the first place, but I was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before and know what's going on. Also, sometimes I use more than one Emp object in a test and therefore it would be very convenient to access them by the id.

Comment: I faced something similar use factory boy package, but again, I should not have relied on ids, because it creates coupling with my database :)
If you use many Emp objects in your setUp method, just name them: `self.emp_1 = Emp.objects.create() ; self.emp_2 = Emp.objects.create()`.
That way it's easy to use them in assert methods :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion @DavidD. :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: By the way, I achieved the same effect like this: 'Emp.objects.order_by('empId')[<empId>]'

Comment: Yep, that's another way :)