# IntegrityError after table restore from backup, PostgreSQL + Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, autofield

I am trying to restore a table in my database from some db backups. The backup is created via `pgAdmin 4` UI tool, select a table and next backup it. And here is the command that `pgAdmin` executes:

```
--file "C:\\Users\\cchie\\DOCUME~1\\DB_BAC~1\\CURREN~1" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --table "public.cosmetic_crawler_currency" "last_cosmetics"
```

The problem is that I have an `AutoField` in that table and when I restore a table, and next try to add new items into it - I have errors like this:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cosmetic_crawler_product_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(27) already exists.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cosmetic_crawler_product_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(27) already exists.
```

As I understand - that means that PostgreSQL server does not know that I have restored the `AutoField` counter and *tries to count from 0*? **Is there a way to fix that and make it count from the last number?**

I was told that I have to use [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14589706/8495108). But when I run `manage.py sqlsequencereset my_app_name` - I see that that command runs:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"cosmetic_crawler_product"','product_id'), coalesce(max("product_id"), 1), max("product_id") IS NOT null) FROM "cosmetic_crawler_product";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"cosmetic_crawler_sale"','sale_id'), coalesce(max("sale_id"), 1), max("sale_id") IS NOT null) FROM "cosmetic_crawler_sale";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"cosmetic_crawler_promo"','promo_id'), coalesce(max("promo_id"), 1), max("promo_id") IS NOT null) FROM "cosmetic_crawler_promo";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"cosmetic_crawler_brand_shops"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "cosmetic_crawler_brand_shops";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"cosmetic_crawler_brand_categories"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "cosmetic_crawler_brand_categories";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"cosmetic_crawler_brand"','brand_id'), coalesce(max("brand_id"), 1), max("brand_id") IS NOT null) FROM "cosmetic_crawler_brand";   
COMMIT;
```

But that still has no effect - when I add new items - PostgreSQL keeps counting from 0 (more precise - from last number where it failed with IntegrityError earlier).

P.S. Restoring process is the same as backuping - manually in `pgAdmin` UI.

Comment: `sqlsequencereset` just prints the commands. It doesn't run them. You have to run the commands.

Comment: so how should I run them?

Comment: Since you're using pgAdmin you could use that, or simply use `manage.py dbshell`.

Comment: ah, sorry, I am quite new here, and don't know exactly how to use that features :) will try your recipe, thank you

Comment: that worked! thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlsequencereset` only prints the commands, it doesn't run them.

You have to run the commands, using `pgAdmin` or `manage.py dbshell`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by "Alasdair" you can get the commands to solve your problem  running `sqlsequencereset`.

or

You can execute the SQL query generated by `sqlsequencereset` from within python in this way (*using the default database*):

```
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from django.db import connection

from myapps.models import MyModel1, MyModel2


sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), [MyModel1, MyModel2])
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for sql in sequence_sql:
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

I tested this code with **Python3.6**, **Django 2.0** and **PostgreSQL 10**.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me, it seems you need to resync your primary key fields in that tables. I solved using PgAdmin4(v7.6).

If you go inside 'Schemas' find 'Tables'.Now Right-click on the table that you updated 'View/Edit Data --> all Rows'. Scroll down on the table and find the last value of "product_id" that has been used.

Now in 'Sequences' you should find 'Schemas' and in the sequence referred at that table 'right-click' and choose 'Properties' and in the 'Definitition Tab' update the 'Current value' with the first available value of the table you updated. Now when you insert a new record in table it start from that value.