# change the initial value of the primary key id, and make start from it on my models

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key

I am working on Django, so I created my table on my models.py. By default when I start registering data, the id, set as primary key, begins with the initial value 1 and increments each time I do a new register.

I have loaded some data in my table, so the final id right now is 185. I run the server and try to add a new register, but I get an error about id duplicity. Django is trying to save the register in id 1.

How do I get it to continue saving the register from id 186 and onwards?

I tried this on my models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, initial=123)
```

but it does not recognize the kwarg `initial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely want to use [sqlsequencereset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset).

You can run it in the terminal and it will output SQL commands for resetting the sequence on every table in the specified module.

`python manage.py sqlsequencereset <your_app_label>`

You can manually run any generated SQL commands, or you can pipe them into django's `dbshell` to run all of them automatically.

`python manage.py sqlsequencereset <your_app_label> | python manage.py dbshell`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14589634/16043283) for more discussion on this topic.

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! after a week of seeking and asking everywhere, I have finally got the correct answer!!!